# "Everything is Uncertain." Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle Question

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I'm new to the concept and only understand that nothing can be measured accurately simultaneously.

Is the statement (in title post) true? Can you also use an example from Quantum Mechanics for the statement?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle

Comment: Thanks Bruce, but I need an explanation since I'm not a Physics expert.

Comment: The problem is that to understand what the uncertainty principle is you need some knowledge of physics. Any non-physics explanation is going to be misleading.

Comment: The statement is, in a certain and very narrow technical sense, true, but that's not what the uncertainty principle is about. If by "accurately", you mean with absolute precision, then you are correct, but then you won't need the second part. Absolute accuracy is limited by the uncertainty principle because the measurement would have to be done by a machine of infinite size, mass, energy and it would take an infinite amount of time.  That, of course, is unphysical. Within the limits of achievable accuracy, the uncertainty principle still sets limits on certain simultaneous measurement.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uncertainty principle never said that nothing can be measured simultaneously with accuracy. Uncertainty principle states that it is not possible to measure two  canonically conjugate quantities at the same time with accuracy. Like you cannot measure the x component of momentum $p_x$ and the x coordinate position simultaneously with accuracy. But the x coordinate of position and the y component of momentum $p_y$ accurately simultaneously.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense, but from a quantum mechanics standpoint how does the uncertainty principle come into play?

Comment: your measurement on a physical quantity induces a new reality associated with the quantities